# java regex string matches two letter countries except a list

Tags: java, regex

I would like a `regex` in java that matches all countries except a list of it.
For example, all countries except spain, i tried:

```
[A-Z]{2}&&^(ES)
```

where

- `PT` should be `true`
- `DE` should be `true`
- `ES` should be `false`

All countries except a list of countries

```
[A-Z]{2}&&^(ES|PT|DE)
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using a **zero-width negative look-ahead** so the final regular expression will be `^(?!ES|PT|DE)[A-Z]{2}$` indicating that you want 2 capital letters except `ES`, `PT` and `DE`. Or simply `(?!ES|PT|DE)[A-Z]{2}` if you use the method [`matches(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) as mentioned by [**@WiktorStribiżew**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew).

Comment: This is right ! just a little thing :p the second parenthesis around ES|PT|DE are not very usefull so we got `(?!DE|ES|PT)[A-Z]{2}` :p

Comment: A would add `^` and `$` anchors to avoid matching 3+ long sequences: https://regex101.com/r/kc79K1/1

Comment: One does not need `^` and `$` at the start/end of pattern with `String#matches()`.

Comment: Or maybe the `\b` anchor is more appropriate :p https://regex101.com/r/kc79K1/2 `\b` anchor match the end or the start of a word